# database connection error associated with the encoding

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, postgresql, encoding

I have `Spring` + `Hibernate` application.

I use PostgreSQL as data store.

application compiles good but when I deployed it to `Tomcat` and launch it I see following stacktrace:

```
  INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/resources/**] onto handler 'org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#0'
    WARN : org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 28P01
    ERROR: org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - ?????: ???????????? "my_db" ?? ?????? ???????? ??????????? (?? ??????)
    WARN : org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 28P01
    ERROR: org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - ?????: ???????????? "my_db" ?? ?????? ???????? ??????????? (?? ??????)
    ERROR: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
    org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:597)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:372)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:417)
    .....
    Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:29)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:426)
    ....
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:556)
    ... 57 more
    Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ?????: ???????????? "my_db" ?? ?????? ???????? ??????????? (?? ??????)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:291)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:108)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:66)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:125)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3Connection.java:30)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3g.AbstractJdbc3gConnection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3gConnection.java:22)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.AbstractJdbc4Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc4Connection.java:30)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.<init>(Jdbc4Connection.java:24)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:393)
    ...
    ... 62 more
```

On another PC this application launch good. Difference: locale. Working PC has English language but another - not.

Please help to find cause of the problem.

**update**

Looks like database doesn't understand password:

from:[PostgreSQL Error Codes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/errcodes-appendix.html)

> 28P01 INVALID PASSWORD invalid_password

### update

I didn't know the cause of the problem but problem disappear after database recreation.

Answer (score 3):

This is a known issue with the PostgreSQL version 3 protocol, where the client doesn't know the encoding to decode error messages sent by the server early in the protocol handshake.

It will be fixed when the version 4 protocol is produced, but that's a long way off yet.

In the mean time the only real workaround is to make sure that the client's default encoding is compatible with the server's. The easiest way to do that is to set `LC_MESSAGES` to something like `en_US.UTF-8`, perhaps via the `lc_messages` option in `postgresql.conf`.