# Unreadable (???) Postgresql exception messages in Idea under Win and Deb

Tags: postgresql, exception, encoding, locale

I tried installing with different locales but it stays the same. Even on linux : all exception messages (system language - Russian) is gibberish with ????

```
SEVERE: �����: ���� ������ "mydb" �� ����������
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: �����: ���� ������ "mydb" �� ����������
```

I can't read it or decode it which annoys me. I can't force it to use different language/encoding either (changing client_encoding does nothing). 
Not with all exceptions though. Mostly this particular one.

Comment: `lc_messages = 'C'                       # locale for system error message` in postgres.conf.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/26220254/398670 among others.